# Ansible hangs on pumactl start

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I have a playbook to install puma on my ec2 instance and everything is fine except when I run `bundle exec pumactl start` at the the end it starts the server but the playbook hangs indefinitely.

Here is the Ansible task -

```
 - shell: /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec pumactl start
   args: 
     chdir: /home/{{ user }}/{{ app_name }}
     warn: no
```

Is there a way to avoid this?

*Update*

I added this to my `/etc/systemd/system/puma.service` file and ran it with systemd as @Michael suggested  -

```
[Unit]
Description=Puma Rails Server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=ubuntu
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/my_app
ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc '/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec puma -C /home/ubuntu/my_app/config/puma.rb'
ExecStop=/bin/bash -lc '/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec pumactl -S /home/ubuntu/my_app/shared/pids/puma.state stop'
TimeoutSec=15
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to daemonize puma, so it's running in the foreground. Ansible has been waiting for it to exit. Add the `-d` option to the command.

Better yet, you should [create a systemd unit to run puma as a service](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/docs/systemd.md), and then [start that service](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/systemd_module.html). Daemonizing is not required in that case, as systemd will handle everything.

BTW, it is best practice to use [`command`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html) instead of `shell` unless you actually need shell processing (which in this case you do not).

Comment: I originally started looking at using systemd but I couldn't get the configuration right. I finally found what I was doing wrong and updated my question though. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.